# How to acces a non returned CharField from models in my views?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Before I start, i want to clarify that I'm a beginner in django and so I'm learning..

This is my models.py

```
    class MyNote(models.Model):
         title_of_note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
         date_created = models.DateTimeField('Created')
         details_note = models.TextField(max_length=2500, default="")
         def __str__(self):
             return self.title_of_note
```

and this is my views.py

```
def index(request):
    notes_list = MyNote.objects.order_by('date_created')
    context  = {'notes_list' : notes_list}
    return render(request, 'note/index.html', context)

def detail(request, note_id):
    note = get_object_or_404(MyNote, pk=note_id)
    return render(request, 'note/detail.html', {'request' : note})
```

My goal is to have a main page /note/ where I can chose from all my notes by the `title_of_note`. And after I chose one of the notes and click the link to one (/note/1/) it displays me the `title_of_note` as a title and underneath the title, I can see my details `details_note`.
Till now, I managed to do the main page with the title of the notes as a link, ordered by the date of creation. It works all fine, but I can't figure it, out how to add the details under the title to the /note/1/ page. So far I understand, I could add `details_note` to the return in my models.py. But I do not know how to really do that, I know I can't just do `return self.title_of_note, self.details_note`.

How do I access `details_note` in my views.py ?

I'm really out of Ideas and hope for some help. This is my first Question on here, so I'm sorry if I did something wrong.

My index template

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<p><font size="5", color="white">You are at the main page of my notes.</p>
{% if notes_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for note in notes_list %}
        <li><font size="3", color="white"><a href="{% url 'note:detail' note.id %}">{{ note.title_of_note }}</a></font></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p><font size="5", color="white">There was a problem. Probably no notes</font></p>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

And here is my detail template

```
<body bgcolor="black">
    <h1><font size="5", color="white">{{ note.title_of_note }}</font></h1>
    <p><font size="3", color="pink">{{ note.details_note }}</font></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you add your templates to the question as well?

Comment: I didn't thought of that. Doing it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your note to the template.

```
def detail(request, note_id):
    note = get_object_or_404(MyNote, pk=note_id)
    context = {'note': note}
    return render(request, 'note/detail.html', context)
```

And in the template you can get the info from the note like this: `{{ note.title_of_note }}` or `{{ note.details_note }}`

In your code you are overwriting the `request` context variable with the `note` instance, don't do that as Django will add a `request` context variable to be available for use in the template.

Comment: I'm so thankful. It worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much